# Magento: Display disabled products on frontend

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I want to show disabled products on front end. But how can I do it??

Although I don't want them to be appeared in catalog or search, but I do want them to be appeared when accessed by direct url saying "Product is Disabled".

Right now view.phtml in catalog/product is not triggering and giving a 404 page.

How can I do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one for only disabled products within a category

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id)
->getProductCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter(
    'status',
    array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED)
);
```

Status Enabled = 1 and Status Disabled = 2

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id)
->getProductCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter(
    'status',
    array('eq' => '2')
);
```

Comment: I mean product page. It is through 404 error. Not in category listing. You are correct when listing products, but I am now sure how to show it in product page.

Comment: Then remove the category filter and just get the products collection  and `addAttributeToFilter` to get disabled products

Comment: I am really sorry for misunderstanding, I am not getting list of products, I am showing single product like http://domain.com/product.html

Comment: When product is disable you cannot show the product page this is default mangento feature

Answer (score 1):

Instead of disabling a product, just remove it from the categories, set it out of stock, set it visible only in catalog, and add a new yes/no attribute called 'is_discontinued' (or something like that). Then, in the product view page check the value of that attribute. If it's 1 the display your message `Product is disabled`. This is how I used to do it and it worked just fine.