# Magento 1.9:- how to show disabled product in product page

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I want to show disabled product details in product page.

I show all product (disabled/enabled) in home page.

but when i clicked disabled product it redirect 404 page.

please let me know how to solved this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch and display the list of disabled products via this

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id)
->getProductCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter(
    'status',
    array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED)
);

foreach ($products as $product){
//fetch product info
}
```

Credit - [Magento: Display disabled products on frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18281442/magento-display-disabled-products-on-frontend)

However , if you are asking about displaying and enabling the customer for addtocart that is not possible .. 
but if you just want to display in product but dont want to allow customer to addtocart then you can try enabling the product but mark it as Out Of Stock in Inventory options of the product

Comment: I want to display product in product details page. in product list page it is working but when I clicked any disabled product it's redirect 404 page..

Comment: You might have to enable the product for that to work, but you can mark the product as Out Of Stock if you dont want customers to buy it ... but u have to enable to display in product detail page